# Tomcat and mySQL configurations

Tags: java, mysql, database, apache, tomcat

I have been using Tomcat and mySQL for quite awhile but recently have been managing to max out my connections. I don't know why as my code opens and closes the connection when its done. For instance here is my connect and close methods:

```
public void closeConnection(){
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void connect(){
    try {
        initCtx = new InitialContext();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

And this is a basic method to execute a generic statement:

```
public void excuteStatement(String query){

        connect();

    try {
        con = ds.getConnection();
        con.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (Exception ex ){               
    } finally {
        if (con != null)
            closeConnection();
    }       
}
```

Is there any reason this sort of code should cause a connection to be left open? I get all the data I need, everything works fine 99% of the time.

This is my configuration in the Tomcat context.xml:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="myUserName" password="myPass" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0000/myUserName"/>
```

Now at this very moment I'm locked out as I have max connections. Should I lower the wait time to avoid this?

One thing I should say about my code, its often that it will trigger many multiple statements in large loops. I think perhaps this rapid opening and closing could be the issue. As my Tomcat servlet is always running should it just open a connection once and leave it open with checks to make sure its still active rather than always opening a connection and closing it?

Thanks for any and all advice on this.

Comment: WRT your question- when your connections max out does your app hang? If so you might be having problems with a combination of synchronization locks in your code and table locks

Comment: What's the actual problem you are seeing? It looks like you're using a connection pool so your connections won't really be being closed, just put back in the pool. This might explain why your connections are being left open!

Comment: How should I use a connection pool? The problem is the database maxes out connections. The app doesnt hang it just cant get any data.

Comment: Do you mean it can't get any new connections at that point? What are the existing connections (and the threads using them) doing? Are the queries 'stuck'? You should be able to find this out from mysql and/or by using a java profiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes decrease your waittime, this is too high. In mysql you can increase the value of max connections, increase it to a sensible size your box can handle..

Comment: What is a sensible wait time?

Comment: @CloudyDna - could you explain why you think decreasing the wait time will help?